# Graph for $\tan(z)=\sin(x)\cos(y)$, and solution for $x$,$y$, and $z$

Tags: trigonometry

What would the graph of $\tan(z)=\sin(x)\cos(y)$ look like?

What is the solution for $x$, $y$, and $z$ (i.e. $x=$, $y=$, $x=$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you query this into Google search, you'll get a pretty neat interactive 3D graph:

"graph of z = arctan(sin(x)*cos(y))"

[image: Pretty neat]

And for the solutions:

$x = \arcsin(\frac{\tan{z}}{\cos{y}})$

$y = \arccos(\frac{\tan{z}}{\sin{x}})$

$z = \arctan(\sin{x}\cdot\cos{y})$

Comment: How does your formulae solve the equation?

Comment: @Momo There isn't enough information to actually solve the equation. But if OP has extra info it will be a matter of substitution.

Comment: Also you should add some $n\pi$ or $2n\pi$ to get all the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Your equation has three unknowns, so it is underdetermined. You have to fix two variables ($x$ and $y$ for example), and solve for $z$. The solutions will be something like:

$z=\tan^{-1}(\sin\alpha\cos\beta)+n\pi\text{, }n\in\mathbb Z$

$x=\alpha$

$y=\beta$